# Export Data Logic

Tags: php, logic, export-to-excel

**My Scenario:**

I have a question regarding exporting data. I have a script in PHP running a complex query that takes some time to return the data.

When I get the data I presented to the user and they have the ability to export if they desired to.

**My logic**

To avoid rerun the query when users export the data I set a Session variable with the data returned by the query and if the user click in export the scripts builds the excel with the data set in a session variable.

**My Problem**

Since the data is store in a session variable if the user runs a different report all the data hold by the session var will be only the last one they ran.

That's the case in drill down on the same report.

**My Questions**

1- How others developer handle this situation ?

2- They just rerun the query one the user click on export data ? (Doesn't matter takes double the time)

3- Set Different session variable one for each report ? (If you have 100 users and 20 reports then you will have 2,000 session variable in case user runs all the reports)

Thank you for your comments.

Comment: You might end up creating a user session table in you database with a timestamp and unique identification for the queries. Best and easiest way to control the user activities and determine a timeout based on sessions time start.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [PHP query caching](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-qc.quickstart.caching.php) to reduce the cost of the second run of the query.

https://blog.engineyard.com/2015/query-caching-with-php-mysqlnd

Comment: Hi Chris, I am using PHP Oracle OCI8

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/oracle-zendcon-php-2009-129471.pdf or http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-caching-pooling-088320.html ... the basic principle is still the same.